# Auth0 must supply HS256, HS384 or HS512 for 'tokenSigningAlg' Error

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt

i'm trying to add Auth0 to my app but when i set the tokenSigningAlg property to RS256 this error pops up

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: You must supply one of HS256, HS384, HS512 for 'tokenSigningAlg' to validate symmetrically signed tokens.

this is the code:

```
const { Router } = require("express")
const router = Router()

const clients = require('./clients.router')
const activities = require('./activities.router')
const publications = require('./publications.router')
const memberships = require("./memberships.router")
const trainer = require('./trainer.router')
const payments = require('./payments.router')
const admin = require('./admin.router')
const testimonials = require('./testimonials.router')


const { auth, requiredScopes } = require('express-oauth2-jwt-bearer');
const dotenv = require('dotenv') 
dotenv.config()
const {AUDIENCE, ISSUER_BASE_URL, TOKENSIGNINGALG} = process.env


dotenv.config()
const checkJwt = auth({
    audience: AUDIENCE,
    issuerBaseURL: ISSUER_BASE_URL,
    tokenSigningAlg: TOKENSIGNINGALG
});


router.use('/clients', clients)
router.use('/activities', activities)
router.use('/publications',checkJwt, publications)
router.use('/trainer', trainer)
router.use('/payments', payments)
router.use('/menberships',memberships)
router.use('/trainer', trainer)
router.use('/admin', admin)
router.use('/testimonials', testimonials)

module.exports = router
```

The TOKENSIGNINGALG variable is set to "RS256" if i change it to any of the options of the error it works but i get an invalid access token, i think i can fix it creating a new API in the auth0 dash board and setting the signing algorithm to HS256 but i would like to use RS256

Comment: Just remove `tokenSigningAlg` altogether. Only asymmetric algorithms fitting keys discovered from the openid metadata document will be supported.

Comment: i tried it and says "You must provide a 'tokenSigningAlg' for validating symmetric algorithms"

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same issue - is no-one else?
Replacing my server.js code with Auth0-generated quickstart js does the same.

Comment: I was running into this, and I realized (after far too much time), that I had added Auth0-known environment variables that seemed to be triggering things in the auth0 lib... in other words, I ended up using the `express-oauth2-jwt-bearer` npm package, but had env variables for the `express-openid-connect` npm package like `CLIENT_ID`, `BASE_URL`, `SECRET`. I removed these env vars, and it started working.
This was especially tricky because setting your repo back won't fix it -- those variables are hiding in your `.env` file (which is likely excluded from git).